# Shortcut for switching contents of monitors

Tags: display, high-sierra, shortcut

I have a three monitor setup: my MacBook screen and two external displays. The first external display is my primary monitor, in the sense that it is directly in front of me; and the other display is secondary. (The laptop screen is used for less important things.)

I often have a full screen terminal on one external display and a maximised web browser open on the other. However, because I prefer the display in front of me, rather than turning my head, I find myself regularly swapping the contents of one display with the other. I do this by swiping up for Mission Control, then dragging the maximised browser to the other screen, then dragging the full-screen terminal over to replace it.

This isn't a difficult or particularly slow process, but it feels suboptimal, given how often I do this (many times a day). Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nothing yet, I'm afraid. Maybe there's a way it can be scripted and assigned to a gesture...

Answer (score 1):

This shortcut might help

fn ⌘ ↓ - combines the contents of both screens into one